# Using a presentation variable in narrative OBIEE 12C

Tags: html, obiee

I'm trying to create a table of contents via the narrative view in OBIEE 12C. I created a prompted link of the destination page and have tried to manipulate it to use my presentation variables, which looks like this: saw.dll?Dashboard&PortalPath=...&Action=Navigate&col1=%22Something%22&valeval1=”@{PV1}”&psa1=%22Something%22

But this does not pass my presentation variables correctly. I've tried a lot of combinations: encoding the quotes, not encoding the quotes, no quotes, … But none of this seems to work. How do I do this? And is there a difference between numeric and non-numeric presentation variables to pass them?

UPDATE: The real code --> `saw.dll?Dashboard&PortalPath=%2Fshared%2FAfdeling%2FDashboards%2FAfdeling&Page=%20Zorgen&Action=Navigate&col1=%22Afdeling%22.%22Afdeling%22&valeval1=”@{PV_Afd}”&psa1=%22Patient%22&col2=%22Forfait%22.%22Code%22&valeval2="@{PV_PROFIEL}"&psa2=%22Patient%22&col3=%22DIM_TIJD%22.%22Maand%20(YYYYMM)%22&valeval3="@{PV_CUR_MONTH}"&psa3=%22Bezoek%22`

Comment: From where are you triggering that link? Is the @{PV1} getting changed by something or just remains there as that?

Comment: This is a presentation variable set in a prompt on my first dashboard page (from where I navigate). When I put a value in this via my prompt, I try to pass this via my narrative :)

Comment: Ok... I think I follow you. What I can tell you is that variables prefixed with @ will be substituted if used in the narrative part of a narrative view (not the prefix, not the postfix). Are you writing your link there?

Comment: Yes, I've actually created a button in the narrative part of the narrative view in which I have included the url I've written before. But in the way I have written it --> "@{PV1} it does not replace it with the value of this presentation value. I've tried a lot of different options: "PV1", 'PV1', '@{PV1}',  %22@{PV1}%22, ... And I have still not found a way in which OBIEE changes the value behind valeval#= to the value I've put in this presentation variable via a dashboard prompt.

Comment: I reproduced the same scenario in my obiee 11g and it works ok... do you mind editing your question to add the code of the narrative? Maybe is some silly thing.

Comment: Remove the quotes, you don't need them. If still doesn't work try to create some columns in your criteria tab and modify the formulas to use your presentation variables. Then in the narrative use @1, @2, etc... instead of the presentation variables

Comment: I've tried both ways. The way of using a column and adding @1 passes the variables to my next analysis but strange enough only to the prompts. It doesn't adapt my analysis to these values unless I click on apply for the prompts. Secondly this way doesn't work for my numeric value (I have 2 non-numeric and 1 numeric value). The @{PV1} in the narrative way passes the numeric value to the other analysis but doesn't adapt my analysis to this value. I don't know how you solved this problem? I really don't see what I am doing wrong. When I click on apply the analysis work so it's not a wrong value.

Comment: I believe I still don't get your scenario... This is what I do: (1) -> create dashboard presentation variable prompt that saves a numeric value in PV1. (2) -> Create a separate analysis with a narrative view where I have a <a> tag with href="saw.dll/..../@{PV1}" (3) -> Add both prompt and analysis to a dashboard page. As soon as I change the prompt and click apply the <a> href is updated. How close is this to your scenario?